# Inflating layouts depending on SwitchCompat state in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView and its every child view has a SwitchCompat.

[image]

Now, my problem is, I want to inflate a layout below it depending on the state of the SwitchCompat.

If isChecked, then

[image]

else

[image]

I implement OnCheckedChangeListener on the Switch but I'm stuck on what to do next. I researched about it too but was unable to find a suitable solution.

```
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    /* Unrelated code */

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_1, null);
    }

    SwitchCompat switchCompat1 = (SwitchCompat) convertView.findViewById(R.id.switchCompat_1);
    switchCompat1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: If your views or layouts are simple ,, then use visibility gone or visible depending on your requirement

Comment: Its not a good practice to inflate here.. If your layout is complex you should try other ways but if its simple changing visibility of views should work

Comment: @user3374345 The layout is just like I the pic i've put up. But the data entered there needs to be sent to the server.

Comment: Add all the views in the layout and setvisibility to visible/gone depending on checked condition

Comment: @user3374345 Alryt, I'll try it out. Thanks.